# It costs $10 a/per person [syntax]

Tags: syntactic-analysis

> a. It costs $10 a person.
>
> b. It costs $10 per person.

Is *a person* part of the noun phrase *$10 a person*? Or is it an adjunct of the verb?

How about *per person*?

Comment: Yes, the NP is $10 a/per person". The postmodifier "a person" is an NP,  "per person" a PP.

Comment: @BillJ How do you know _a/per person_ is not an adjunct of the verb?

Comment: Because "a person" / "per person" combine with $10 to form a constituent, cf. "$10 a / per person is what it costs". Thus their function in the NP can only be that of postmodifier.

Comment: Per/a person are two distributive adjuncts that modify $10. They have indipendent status as adjuncts, as the displacement test shows: "per person it costs..."

Comment: per = for every; per person = for every person. It costs $10 for every person. It costs what? $10 (NP). Now, we can review per person in two ways: a) It costs per person, and b) $10 per person.

Comment: @Nico Adjuncts are modifiers in clause structure, not noun phrase structure. "A person" is an NP and "per person" is a PP. They each function as postmodifier of "$10", and combine with it to form the constituent "$10 a / per person", a noun phrase.

Comment: @BillJ In your opinion maybe... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjunct_(grammar)

Answer (score 3):

> [1] *It costs* [*$10 a person*].
>
> [2] *It costs* [*$10 per person*].

The bracketed elements in [1] and [2] are noun phrases functioning as direct object of "costs". The only difference is that in [1] "a person" is a noun phrase and in [2] "per person" is a preposition phrase. In both cases they are postmodifiers of "$10", and they combine with it to yield the larger bracketed noun phrases.

We know that "$10 a person" and "$10 per person" are constituents since they are portable, cf. "[$10 a person] is what it cost" / "[$10 per person] is what it costs", where the bracketed noun phrases function as subject of the sentence.

Comment: The sentence is basically "*It costs $10*". We can say 1. "*It costs $10 per person*" 2. "*Per person, it costs $10*"; 3. "*It costs, per person, $10*". The freedom within the sentence indicates an adverbial phrase. “*A person*” is information **additional to** "It costs $10". It could be seen as 4. "*It costs a (one) person $10.*" In this, “*a (one) person*” is the indirect object. All indirect objects can be the object of “to or “for” in the manner of the OE dative (also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dative_shift.) The addition of a preposition shows the equivalence with “per person.”

Comment: What sort of cock-eyed grammar is that? They are not adverbial phrases. "A person" and "per person" are an NP and a PP respectively, both functioning as postmodifier of $10. It's as simple as that.

Comment: @Greybeard Yes, Bill is confusing morphological case with functional case...

Comment: @Nico  "Case" is about an inflectional system of the noun -- totally irrelevant here.  Here's an example from CGEL p408 "It costs [$20 a yard/person]" where the brackets mark "$20 a yard/person" as an NP.

Comment: @BillJ Have I ever dismissed the status of "a person" as a NP? I fear you are misreading me, whatever the reason might be. English does not display morphological dative marking, but indirect objects cover the same function. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dative_case#Modern_English

Comment: @Nico so what is the relevance of your first comment to a simple case of the internal structure of an NP structure consisting of head + postmodifier?

Comment: @Nico I've already said that in my 2nd comment in Greybeard's answer.

Comment: @BillJ "*What sort of cock-eyed grammar is that?*" Whatever it is it is not the Holy Writ of Messrs P & H, is it? Perhaps it is heretical? In truth, it is quite simple grammar.

Comment: @BillJ My comment is a comment. If you don't like it, just skip it. Moreover, I would ask you to moderate your tone altogether!

Comment: @Nico Stick to the core question, and do not waste time talking about dative case, which you seem intent on doing. If you don't see $10 a/per person" as an NP, that's up to you. I suggest you post your own answer.

Comment: @BillJ I suggest you stop telling me what I have to do and read exactly what I write!

Comment: @Nico And you write about 'confusing morphological case with functional case', which is totally irrelevant to the structure of the NP in question. You're off-topic.

Comment: If _per person_ is not an adjunct of the clause, how would you be able to explain its movability? _Per person, it costs $10._ _It, per person, costs $10._ _It costs $10 per person._

Comment: @listeneva That proves nothing. The fact is that "$10 a/per person" is a noun phrase, a constituent in "$10 a/per person is what it cost". What else could it possibly be?

Comment: True, _$10 per person is what it costs_ (or _What it costs is $10 per person_) shows that _$10 per person_ can be a constituent. But there can be another cleft version made out of (b) that shows _$10 per person_ is not a single constituent.  And that version is _$10 is what it costs per person_ (or _What it costs per person is $10_). The same could probably be said about (a).

Answer (score -1):

[Quotes from the OED:]

"A" was a preposition (in, on, by, at). As a general preposition is now mainly restricted to dialect. In its role as a preposition, it was used

> With adverbs of repetition (as once, twice, many times, oft a day); now classified as the indefinite article: see *[the entry for "a" at]* adj. 4.

**adj. 4.**

> 4. Used to express a rate or ratio: in, to, or for each, per:  (a) originally (with adverbs of repetition) of occurrences within a period of time;  (b) subsequently, relating an amount of money to a period of time;  (c) hence expressing rate or proportion in general, i.e. of money value, volume, weight, etc., to a unit of another kind, an individual, etc. (cf. apiece adv.). Cf. aday adv. 1.
>
> In sense 4(a)   originally the preposition a defining time (see a prep.1 3), but probably already in Middle English identified with the indefinite article; influence of the Old English construction seen in "on anum monðe"† (see quot. OE2) is also possible.
>
> five-, seven-, etc. a-side: see side n.1 Phrases 7.

†(OE   Byrhtferð Enchiridion (Ashm.) (1995) iii. ii. 144   Þonne getimað hyt þæt hig wrixliað twia **on** anum monðe.] )

> 2005   Independent 3 Nov. 41/2   *A man or woman..who can..charge several thousand pounds a day without laughing.*

Personally, I see "a" in "$10 a person" as a preposition: either that or a dative = "for a person" - thus an adjunct.

Comment: How can it be an adjunct when it's clearly part of the NP? Adjuncts are modifiers in clause structure, not NP structure. I'd say that the NP "a day" and the PP "per day" are best analysed as postmodifiers of $10.

Comment: If you see "a day/person" as {preposition + noun} then you have a modifier/PP. -- If you see "a day/person" as a dative, then you have an NP. -- If you see the dative as implying a "for" (e.g. He baked **her** a cake) then you have an NP acting as a PP. -- The sentence is basically "It [the price] is $10"  ("to be" is an equivalence marker) and "a day/person" modifies ambiguously(?) both "It [the price]" and "$10". -- I suspect that is how it can be an adjunct.

Comment: Eh? You're missing the point. Adjuncts are modifiers in clause structure, not phrase structure. In "$10 a day", "a day" is an NP modifying "$10", and in "$10 per day", "per day" is a PP also modifying "$10". The NP $10 a/per day" is direct object of "cost". We know that "$10 a/per day" is an NP since it forms a movable constituent, e.g. "$10 a/per day" is what it costs. Incidentally, English does not have a dative case.

Comment: @BillJ "*Incidentally, English does not have a dative case*". if you believe that is so, then the "if" condition will not apply to you.

Comment: The dative case was lost in earlier stages of the language. A simple fact.

Comment: I think you're right that _per person_ can be moved about in the sentence without changing the meaning. _Per person, it costs $10._ _It, per person, costs $10._ _It costs $10 per person._ But the same is not exactly the case with _a person_. ?? _A person, it costs $10._ ?? _It, a person, costs $10._ Therefore, I can accept that _per person_ is an adjunct, but I can't accept that _a person_ is an adjunct as well.

Comment: It's interesting. Having had a look at more reference books, the conclusion is that "a" is a preposition, which, in combination with a noun (phrase) will produce a modifier. Compare "ahead; aboard; agape; alone.